# Regex string that searches for single quote number single quote

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of `'3','19','27'` and I need to go through the string and see if `2 3 4 19 and 27` are in there. As of right now I'm using `indexOf` to check if the number is in the string.
If I search for `2`  it will always bring back a value.

**Question :** How would I write an regex exp to search if 2 is behind or in front of single quotes.

**Example:**

```
('2','19') = TRUE
('19','27') = FALSE
```

I need this to work with every single digit.

Comment: Using standard JavaScript: `/'2'/.test(myString)`.

Comment: Sorry I mean any single digit

Comment: Then use `/'\d'/.test(myString)`.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "jQuery regex".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the Regex dynamically using `RegExp`. It will console the matched elements.

```js
var string = "'3','19','27','49'",arr = [1,2,3,27,46], regex;
for(var i=0,n=arr.length;i<n;i++)
{
    regex = new RegExp("'"+arr[i]+"'");
    if(regex.test(string)) console.log(arr[i]);
}
```